# How to retrieve username & passwords stored in Webkit browser?

Tags: android, browser, webkit, passwords

I would like to get access to Webkit browser internals - namely where to get username/passwords stored by browser?

Is it possible or not? I'm looking for programmatic way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No way. Browser is a separate application and is protected by Android's [security architecture](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html), where each app is assigned a unique userID and credentials set so that apps do not have privileges to see each others files or data.